# matrix add image

Tags: matrix

I am unable to add even a single image when trying to publish or edit content. Clicking the "Add Image" link does nothing. I'm assuming this something to do with my EE installation, but can find anything to help fix it. I opened a JavaScript console and the following errors do display:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'corner' template_variables.js:6
(anonymous function) template_variables.js:6
m jquery.js:43
l.fireWith jquery.js:44
b.extend.ready jquery.js:33
k.addEventListener.A jquery.js:42
yui: Modules missing: oop,event-custom-base,dom-core,dom-base,selector-native,selector,node-core,node-base,event-base,event-delegate,node-event-delegate,node-pluginhost,dom-style,dom-style-ie,dom-screen,node-screen,node-style,json-parse,json-stringify,pluginhost-base,pluginhost-config, 21 Controller_default_d34ceebffe812545808c75cbba886977.js:1
yui: Modules missing: pluginhost-base,pluginhost-config, 2 Controller_default_d34ceebffe812545808c75cbba886977.js:1

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tablesorter' compressed.js:39
(anonymous function) compressed.js:39
m jquery.js:43
l.fireWith jquery.js:44
b.extend.ready jquery.js:33
k.addEventListener.A jquery.js:42
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using EE 2.5.2 and Matrix 2.5.3

Thank you!

Keith Miller

Comment: When you installed matrix, did you add it's theme files in your third party themes folder?

Comment: That is my first thought as well, mjr.  Re-uploading the third_party/themes/matrix folder would be my first recommendation.

Comment: Have you resolved this yet? My advice would be to re-install Matrix, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your install of the Matrix addon is missing something.

I suggest you start over by reuploading the theme files into /themes/third_party/matrix and the addon files to /system/expressionengine/third_party/matrix.

Then in your control panel navigate to Addons > Fieldtypes and uninstall then reinstall Matrix.

Make sure to backup your database if you are concerned about losing any data.